# angular2: issue displaying a component template in another component's template when routing with a parameter

Tags: angular

I am trying to route to a stockTransactions view which takes a productCode parameter and then displays a table of stockTransactionItems... when I build the app using ng-cli I don't get any errors but when I navigate to the app in chrome it just says loading with the below error message in the developer console...  It seems like it can't use or find the stock-transaction-item selector/component...  I imported the StockTransactionItemComponent in app.module and in the past i've done similar things with no issues...  Any idea what might be going wrong here?

*my error (code is below error):*

> zone.js:388Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
>       Can't bind to 'stock-transaction-item' since it isn't a known property of 'tr'. ("
>                 
>                 
>                     ][stock-transaction-item]="stockTransactionItem">
>                 
>             
>       "): StockTransactionsComponent@14:63 ; Zone:  ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Error: Template parse errors:
>       Can't bind to 'stock-transaction-item' since it isn't a known property of 'tr'. ("
>                 
>                 
>                     ][stock-transaction-item]="stockTransactionItem">
>                 
>             
>       "): StockTransactionsComponent@14:63

**stock-transactions.component.html:**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-push-3">
        <div class="col-md-8" *ngIf="stockTransactions">
        <h1>Stock Transactions</h1>
        <table class="table table-hover">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Date</th>
                    <th>Type</th>
                    <th>Supplier</th>
                    <th>Qty</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr *ngFor="let stockTransaction of stockTransactions" [stock-transaction-item]="stockTransaction"></tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

**stock-transactions.component.ts:**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

import { StockTransactionModel } from '../../models/stock-transaction.model';
import { RestService } from '../../services/rest.service';
@Component({
  selector: '[stock-transaction]',
  templateUrl: './stock-transactions.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./stock-transactions.component.css']
})
export class StockTransactionsComponent implements OnInit {
    stockTransactions: Array<StockTransactionModel>;
    productCode: string;


  constructor(private restService: RestService, private route: ActivatedRoute) { 

  }


  showStockTransactions(productCode: string) {
        this.restService.getStockTransactions(productCode)
            .subscribe(
            (res) => {
                this.stockTransactions = res;
                console.log(this.stockTransactions);
            },
            (res) => {
                console.log("failure " + res);
            }
            );
    }

  ngOnInit() {
      this.productCode = this.route.snapshot.params['productCode']          
    this.showStockTransactions(this.productCode);
  }

}
```

**stock-transaction-item.component.html:**

```
    <td>{{stockTransactionItem?.Date | date}}</td>
    <td>{{stockTransactionItem?.TransactionType_Name}}</td>
    <td>{{stockTransactionItem?.SupplierMaster_Name}}</td>
    <td>{{stockTransactionItem?.Qty}}</td>
```

**stock-transaction-item.ts:**

```
    import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

import { StockTransactionModel } from '../../models/stock-transaction.model';


@Component({
  selector: 'stock-transaction-item',
  templateUrl: './stock-transaction-item.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./stock-transaction-item.component.css']
})
export class StockTransactionItemComponent implements OnInit {
@Input("stock-transaction-item") stockTransactionItem: StockTransactionModel;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not using the right selector for `stock-transaction-item`. On the other hand, camelCase is advised for attribute selectors. Change your template to:

**stock-transactions.component.html:** (part)

```
<tbody>
   <tr *ngFor="let transItem of stockTransactions" [stockTransactionItem]="transItem"></tr>
</tbody>
```

and change your `StockTransactionItemComponent` to:

```
@Component({
  selector: '[stockTransactionItem]', //attribute selector
  templateUrl: './stock-transaction-item.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./stock-transaction-item.component.css']
})
export class StockTransactionItemComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() //no need to specify this anymore
  stockTransactionItem: StockTransactionModel;

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {}

}
```

Comment: Thanks @PierreDuc it's working fine now!  Can you please explain to my why the selector needs to be inside []?

Comment: It's an [attribute selector](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/attribute-directives.html). So a property on an html element. If you use it without the brackets it will only work if you make it an html element: `<stock-transaction-item></stock-transaction-item>`. You can also refer [**here**](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) for default selectors